# Do custom configs get cached on runtime by CLR

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

If I create custom configuration files (for example: *myconfig.config*) would that be also get cached by CLR like it caches the *app.config* and *web.config*?

Comment: Unless they are linked directly in app.config or web.config, I think not.

Comment: You meant to say if i refer myconfig.config in web/app.config it caches the entire myconfig.config file along with the reference part or it caches only reference?? Thanks